# Hide network path displayed in mapped drive name

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, network-share, storage-area-network

Is there a way to hide the network path that is displayed by default in a mapped drive name?

We've got Windows 7 and XP machines and we're migrating from a fileserver to a SAN.

Currently in My Computer, the mapped network drives have the full label:

```
N (\\<servername) (N:)
```

Can we set something in Group Policy or in the mapping script (VBScript) that will set it to simply:

```
N:
```

or

```
N: (Mapped Drive)
```

or similar?

Comment: Do you mean that you are migrating to a NAS? A SAN generally implies block storage, meaning the storage is presented to a server as locally attached disk. A NAS looks like a network drive/file server to the clients.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built-in functionality to do what you're looking for. Really, why does it matter anyway? Most users aren't going to care that the path to the "drive" changes, so long as they can get to what they need.

Comment: Heh.  This right after all of our home drive shares changed and Win7 decides it only wants to sporadically maintain the mappings...  Found out how many users really do know how to map a network drive.

Comment: @squillman: Hmm... odd. Are they specified as a legacy home directory path in the user's account object properties? We haven't seen that problem, albeit we're got sub-1000 Windows 7 clients, total, within all our Customer sites.

Comment: Actually, I sit corrected.  The mappings would magically disappear prior to the shares changing.  They were previously mapped in the login script and now are specified on the user's account object.  The shares changed at the same time that they switched over to using the account objects.